# Is there a way to install the original Command and Conquer on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-and-conquer

Is there any way to install C&C on Windows 7 without the XP VM?

- I tried using the XP virtual mode but I guess my laptop is not compatible with it.
- I tried changing the compatibility in the properties as stated to Win 95 and I tried all the others too, but I still get the error:

  > The version is not compatible with the version of windows. Check the systems info to see whether you need a 32 bit or 64 bit version of the program and then contact the software provider."

Is there any way I can get it to install and work?

Comment: There is a version of C&C being made in HTML5 while you figure this out http://www.adityaravishankar.com/projects/games/command-and-conquer/

Comment: What specific C&C games are you looking to install? Red Alert Soviet/Allies ? Tiberian Sun? Aftermath? Generals? Red Alert 2?

Comment: XP Mode on Windows 7 is not meant to allow you to play your old games, just legacy business (i.e., non-game) apps. But even if it did that wouldn't help since C&C didn't even work in XP neither (AFAIK). You would have had to go back to Windows 98 to be able to play.

Answer (score 7):

Install the patch by nyerguds - http://nyerguds.arsaneus-design.com/cnc95upd/cc95p106/

This patch lets you play C&C on newer OS's and with higher resolutions. Also lots of bug fixes in it.....

EDIT: There is a patched installer available for download here with details... http://digiex.net/downloads/download-center-2-0/games/2929-command-conquer-gold-full-hard-disk-install.html

Comment: Note to anyone reading this now: the digiex download is _very_ outdated by now. There's a full installer download link on my main site (the first link) too, so just use that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting shows you're trying to run a 16-bit executable (for DOS or Windows 3.1) on a 64-bit version of Windows - which isn't possible due to the way 64-bit processors work when running in 64-bit mode.

To the best of my knowledge, there was no Windows 3.1 version of C&C, so unless the Windows 95 version of C&C used a 16-bit installer (it *could* have - some games did, although I don't think this is one of them), that tells me you're trying to play the DOS version.

If that is the case, I recommend you download and install [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). DOSBox emulates a complete DOS PC, which makes it ideal for running these old games. If you're not used to working with DOS, it might take you a little while to get used to the program. If you need help, the [DOSBox Wiki](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Main_Page) contains information on how to use DOSBox and basic DOS commands.

AFAIK, C&C requires the CD to be present, so you may prefer to create ISO images of your CDs and mount the appropriate one in DOSBox prior to starting the game. You can also use an external image mounting tool and simply point DOSBox at that drive.

Comment: No, the 32-bit Win95 version of the game sadly DOES use a 16-bit windows program as CD installer. Blame InstallShield for that piece of brilliance. The link Aditya gave has a full installer I created exactly to get around that problem.

Comment: On a related note, the game has always contained its own No-CD system, a leftover from the beta testing phases. They simply never removed it. It can be used as command line parameter, `-cdPATH/TO/USE/AS/CD` (both relative and absolute paths work. Classic way is using `-cd.`, for 'current directory'). My 1.06 patch offers it as actual configuration option in the config tool / config file

Answer (score 0):

Just download the No-CD version of the game from the official site: it works in Windows 7 64-bit edition. However, you have to download the movie clips separately.

Comment: Hi there.  It's pretty hard to understand what you're answer is here.  Can you try to be a little more clear?

Comment: This post possibly refers to the versions of C&C (Tiberium Dawn, Tiberian Sun and Red Alert) that used to be available to download on the official C&C site two years ago (see [this](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/c-and-c-tiberian-sun-turned-into-freeware) article). These versions have since been pulled - possibly due to the _C&C: The First Decade_ bundle being made available to buy on Origin in some regions.

Comment: Incorrect. They only took them down them because they were already mirrored on other sites. The first three games ARE officially freeware. tombooo refers to the full game install pack I created to get around the 16-bit installer problem. I agree with GnomeSlice though, giving the link to said full download would've been useful, though Aditya already posted it now.